# Add dynamic page as funnel step in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I want to add as the first step of my funnel a dynamic page like this /profile/personal?new=1&ref_product_id=21666, where the id number is dynamic

It would be great to have some help with the best Regex for this type of situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should cover it:

`^/profile/personal\?new=1&ref_product_id=[0-9]+`

Comment: I don't know why but it's not working. When I search for this regex in the All Pages report it shows me the pages, but in the funnel it continues to have zero pages.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your funnel configuration?

Comment: Sure, here it goes: https://imgur.com/a/rly6SrP The regex in the 1st step is: ^/candidatos/wizard/personal\?new=1&ref_job_id=[0-9]+

Comment: Thanks. Change 'Equals to` to `Regex match`. Also change your goal value to `/candidatos/perfils\?wizard_resume_uploaded=1`

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to test it that way. I have another funnel with /candidatos/perfil?wizard_resume_uploaded=1 as destination page (Equals to) and it works fine